# Google map Highlight Country With Border using polygon

Tags: asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map and want to highlight multiple countries using its country border lines lat lng information. I am drawing polygon but I want information for each country borders.

From where can I get those information to highlight country using polygon? Or is there any other good way to highlight countries?

Below link shows what I want to do..
http://www.dyngeometry.com/web/WorldRegion.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally its done..

http://www.icgg.org/corruption.cpi_2008_worldmap.html

Above link have all data and countries coordinates for borders.

Comment: I suggest you mark the answer as accepted, so people can see that it is solved, (yellow), on the list of questions.

Comment: Yes, But it says Yellow warning "You can accept your own answer in 22 hours." :)

Comment: Do you know How to achieve this but with smooth border lines to rectangles and triangles straight lines on the borders like you did?