# How to auto mark regions in google maps in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps

I want to display a google maps in my browser. I am thinking of using the plugin

http://gmap3.net/

However the main issue is I want to mark a region instead of a point. For example, if I say "Pacific Ocean", I don't want a point in the center, I want the whole ocean marked visually. Possibly the region can be a certain color, and if you hover over it, the region becomes more opaque and maybe a hover tooltip shows.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Outline areas on a Google Map using Google Map API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184584/outline-areas-on-a-google-map-using-google-map-api-v3)

Comment: This requires you to know the coordinates which make the boundry. I just want to give a string of a location, and google should automatically convert it into a region.

Comment: That functionality isn't available directly from Google Maps.  You might be able to find data as KML or in FusionTables that lets you do what you want (but you still have to find the data).

Comment: @omega You'll have to provide the coordinates of the boundaries to define the polygon — how'd you expect Google to know how the boundary you intend around a single point to be delimited based on a single pair of coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the example at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-simple.

It appears to be relatively straightfoward. Hope this helps!

Comment: This requires you to know the coordinates which make the boundry. I just want to give a string of a location, and google should automatically convert it into a region.

Comment: Ok, I understand, will have a look for you now.

Comment: This doesn't appear possible to do automatically at the moment. The only solution I can think  of is using the API to find the co-ordinates of the points of the polygon, and then plot it. You could probably create your own plugin to do this.

Comment: How do you use the API to find the co-ordinates? I thought that wasn't possible. I thought you had to manually get the coordinates.

Comment: Look at geocoding on the Google Maps API

Comment: The Google Maps Geocoding API does not return polygons (at least at present), only the suggested viewport and bounds for the location in question.

Comment: One of the parameters it returns is a longitude and latitude, see [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#GeocodingResponses). You could then input these in order to create a polygon. @geocodezip

Comment: @omega If you liked my response, could you accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: @zak-cutner A latitude and longitude is not adequate to create a polygon (to display a region).  The bounds object contains 2 sets of coordinates (two corners of a rectangle), and can be used to a rectangle, however, most regions (like the pacific ocean) are not rectangular.