# Area/Boundary lat long of a location of a given area

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

Suppose I search using a location something like (Texas) now I want to mark the area of Texas using a polygon. So for drawing polygon i need the the lat long of that area. I search in google and discuss with some of my friend i found those links. From those links I understand that google doesn't provide the information. 
I need a solution in google map V2 so that i can implement it in my android project. So my question is how can i get those area lat long? Here is some link of my requirement-

[Google Maps how to Show city or an Area outline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31861822/google-maps-how-to-show-city-or-an-area-outline/31865958#31865958)

[Outline areas on a Google Map using Google Map API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184584/outline-areas-on-a-google-map-using-google-map-api-v3)

[Highlighting borders of state and cities of US in Google Map API 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388590/highlighting-borders-of-state-and-cities-of-us-in-google-map-api-3)

And here is some screenshot-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_TUaWwnPSeHbnZlc0hWbzZPcmM/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_TUaWwnPSeHWUg2WDdkMUs1TjA/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out Google's developer guide for Geocoding: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: OK Checking as per i know Google does not provide the information.

Comment: **It always gives you a square box, But requirement is something like this** 
[link](https://drive.google.com/a/technoexponent.com/file/d/0B_TUaWwnPSeHbnZlc0hWbzZPcmM/view)

Comment: You're requesting something you'll need to do on your end as Google is giving you the smallest area it can resolve to that lat/long set. This isn't a lack of features so much as the best you can get without resolving more and more decimal places in the coordinates.

You need to retrieve the lat/long of each point where you'll start a new segment from (I'd take the center of the box given by Google) while building the polygon. This was mentioned in your first link as the recommended answer.